# load R dataset in a javascript script

Tags: javascript, r, knitr

I have the following issue  :
I am working on knitr, and I am running a js script on it.
I need to use some variables from a dataset (stored in a folder as a .rda file).
To achieve this, I tried two different ways :
1.  Either using ocpu.call with the function identity in order to run the R code in the variable “codeR”.

```
<script>
//because identity is in base
ocpu.seturl("//public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/base/R")

//actual handler
$("#submitbutton").on("click", function(){
    var codeR = "load(\"z.RData\"); r_var;"

//arguments
var mysnippet = new ocpu.Snippet(codeR);

//disable button
$("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");

//perform the request
var req = ocpu.call("identity", {
    "x" : mysnippet
}, function(session){
    session.getConsole(function(outtxt){
        $("#output").text(outtxt); 
    });
});

//if R returns an error, alert the error message
req.fail(function(){
    alert("Server error: " + req.responseText);
});      

req.always(function(){
    $("button").removeAttr("disabled");    
});
});   
</script>$
```

in this case
          load(\"z.RData\");
doesn't work

2. Or using R chunks into the js code:

   ````
       mapNavigation: {
       enabled: true,
       buttonOptions: {
           verticalAlign: 'bottom'
       }
   },

   series: [{
       name: 'Countries',
       color: '#E0E0E0',
       enableMouseTracking: false
   }, {
       type: 'mapbubble',
       point: {
                   events: {
                       click: pointClick
                   }
               },
       name: 'Population 2013',
       joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
       data: data,
       minSize: ```{r}10```,
       maxSize: '12%',
       tooltip: {
           pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.z} thousands'
       }
   }]
   ````

   });

   });
     
   in this case
     `{r}10` 
   is not understood in the script
   But both ideas don’t work, and I tried many other things as well, so now I am a little bit lost…

Thank you a lot in advance for your help !!

Keivan